# WooCommerce send email on a scheduled date

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am working on a custom Wordpress / WooCommerce plugin development, the point is: customer orders a medical treatment and schedules treatment date (for an instance, he orders today and schedules his treatment in 16 days 2/28/2021), plugin should check that date in the db table (let's assume that we fetch that from `wp_usermeta` table under `meta_key => 'treatment_date'`) and set a trigger mail function 7 days before the treatment date. Mail function should e-mail customer that he's left 7 days until his treatment.

This is going to be developed as a custom plugin.

Any ideas how should look like that mail trigger function?

Comment: For scheduled events you can use this incredible and powerful library that WooCommerce and WooCommerce Subscriptions uses. You can test that with [**this plugin**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/action-scheduler/) and see all [related documentation and usage examples](https://actionscheduler.org/)… The library to be integrated in plugins is [**here on Github**](https://github.com/woocommerce/action-scheduler/).

Comment: That is actually really useful library. Thank you @LoicTheAztec